# How to get latitude and longitude from google maps v3 api?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying create a map using google maps v3 api. I have found the below code over internet and I want to show the latitude and logitude in map window instead of address.

```
<script>
      function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8688, 151.2195),
          zoom: 13,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),
          mapOptions);

        var input = document.getElementById('searchTextField');
        var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);

        autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          map: map
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
          infowindow.close();
          marker.setVisible(false);
          input.className = '';
          var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
          if (!place.geometry) {
            // Inform the user that the place was not found and return.
            input.className = 'notfound';
            return;
          }

          // If the place has a geometry, then present it on a map.
          if (place.geometry.viewport) {
            map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
          } else {
            map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
            map.setZoom(17);  // Why 17? Because it looks good.
          }
          var image = {
            url: place.icon,
            size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
            origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
            anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
            scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(35, 35)
          };
          marker.setIcon(image);
          marker.setPosition(place.geometry.location);
          marker.setVisible(true);

          var address = '';
          if (place.address_components) {
            address = [
              (place.address_components[0] && place.address_components[0].short_name || ''),
              (place.address_components[1] && place.address_components[1].short_name || ''),
              (place.address_components[2] && place.address_components[2].short_name || '')
            ].join(' ');
          }

          infowindow.setContent('<div><strong>' + place.name + '</strong><br>' + address);
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        });
```

Please some one help me to get and show latitude and longitude. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Where you have

```
  var address = '';
  if (place.address_components) {
    address = [
      (place.address_components[0] && place.address_components[0].short_name || ''),
      (place.address_components[1] && place.address_components[1].short_name || ''),
      (place.address_components[2] && place.address_components[2].short_name || '')
    ].join(' ');
  }

  infowindow.setContent('<div><strong>' + place.name + '</strong><br>' + address);
  infowindow.open(map, marker);
```

Change the infowindow line to read

```
  infowindow.setContent('<div><strong>' + place.name + '</strong><br>' + place.geometry.location.lat() + ',' + place.geometry.location.lng());
```

Comment: Thanks, it solves my problem. But I have another question is it possible to only show the lat,lon and address with out showing the map. If possible how.

Comment: Please read the [terms of use](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#tos).  It looks [like](https://developers.google.com/places/uplift?hl=en) you can display places content without a map, but you have to display a "powered by google" logo.  Not sure what you would need the coordinates for if you don't have a map.  You probably don't want to use the Google Maps API v3 in that case, just the [Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/).

Comment: I just asked to know about it. I will show it on map. 
BTW, I also want to show city name and abbreviation of state.
say for Princeton, New Jersey. I want to show princeton,nj.
How to do this or is it possible to get state name abbreviation ?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding#ReverseGeocoding that might help you out. Scroll down a bit and it shows some possiblities.

Comment: @Rafe I am using place.address_components[2].short_name to fetch state. It works fine for some city but not for all. Like for arizona it gives TypeError: place.address_components[2] is undefined
How to handle this error ?

Answer (score 10):

Much simpler solution will be :

```
var address = "New Delhi"
$.ajax({
  url:"http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address="+address+"&sensor=false",
  type: "POST",
  success:function(res){
     console.log(res.results[0].geometry.location.lat);
     console.log(res.results[0].geometry.location.lng);
  }
});
```

Cheers

Comment: How does this not trigger a "same origin" domain problem?

Comment: @FranciscoPresencia : It does not throw cross domain issue..:).. You can simply run it for yourself and see..:)

Comment: Pretty sure that's against the ToS. Why not use the more user-friendly [Autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform)?

Comment: @Walf :  Checkout : https://developers.google.com/terms/ Only limitation that google does is limit the number of requests. If we want to have like 10k requests per day, then we can go with the paid option.

Answer (score 7):

Take a look at this code..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>
    <script>
        function initialize() {
        var address = 'Kolkata';
            geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
            geocoder.geocode({
            'address': address
            }, function(results, status) {      
                var lat=document.getElementById("lat").innerHTML=results[0].geometry.location.lat();    
                var lng=document.getElementById("lng").innerHTML=results[0].geometry.location.lng();        
            });
        }
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <p id="lat"></p> 
    <p id="lng"></p> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `geometry.location.lat()` The perfect answer.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you might be looking for just regular geolocation stuff? Here's my snippett from a project to grab a user's lat/long

trigger show_user_location(); to begin the geolocation API.

```
function show_user_location(){ 

    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(display_user_location, error_response); 
} 
function display_user_location(user_position){ 
    var lat = user_position.coords.latitude; 
    var lon = user_position.coords.longitude; 

// once we get here make that AJAX query
// #loc.value="<p>Your latitude is: "+lat+", your longitude is: "+lon+"</p>"+ "<p><a href='http://maps.google.com/?q="+lat+","+lon+"'>View your location on Google Maps</a></p>";

    // I often put the lat/lon in a hidden form for later retrieval here.
    // value = document.getElementById('lat').value;
    // value = document.getElementById('lat').value;

    document.getElementById("lat").value = lat;
    document.getElementById("long").value = lon;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you want the lat and long of any part of the map,try adding the click listeners for the map not the marker. The code should be something like below:

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);

    service.getDetails({
        placeId: 'ChIJN1t_tDeuEmsRUsoyG83frY4'
    },function(place,status){
        if(status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK)
        {
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map:map,
                position: place.geometry.location

            });

        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(e) {
          infowindow.setContent('<div>'+'Longitute'+'<strong>' + e.latLng.lng() + '</strong><br>' +
            'Latitude:'+'<strong>' + e.latLng.lat()+'</strong>'  + '</div>');
          infowindow.open(map, this);
        });
        }
    });
```

This will display the lat and long of any location on the map using a info window.

Answer (score 1):

I created a tiny component to illustrate with `React`. Although, it's the same `API`. I thought this might be helpful.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { GoogleApiWrapper } from 'google-maps-react';

const SearchLocation = ({ google }) => {
  const [inputData, setInputData] = useState('');

  const handleChange = ({ target: { value } }) => {
    if (value) {
      setInputData(value);
      const autoCompleteService = new google.maps.places.AutocompleteService();
      autoCompleteService.getPlacePredictions(
        { input: value },
        (predictions, status) => {
           if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
              // update prediction, so that user can click on the predicted address
              const updatePredictions = (predictions) => {};
              // or get the coordinate of one prediction
              if (predictions.length > 0) {
                 geoCodeLocation(predictions[0]);
              }
           }
        }
      );
    }
  };

  const geoCodeLocation = (suggestion) => {
    const placeId = suggestion.place_id;
    const GeoCoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    GeoCoder.geocode({ placeId }, (response) => {
      const lattitude = response[0].geometry.location.lat();
      const longitude = response[0].geometry.location.lng();
      const coordinates = [longitude, lattitude];
      // save coordinate and suggestion
      const selectLocation = ({ coordinates, suggestion }) => {};
    });
  };

  return (
    <div>
        <input
          type="text"
          name="searchLocation"
          placeholder="Enter your address..."
          className="text-field"
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
      {/* handle suggestion */}
   </div>
  );
};

export default GoogleApiWrapper({
  apiKey: process.env.GOOGLE_API_KEY,
  v: '3'
})(SearchLocation);

SearchLocation.defaultProps = {};

SearchLocation.propTypes = {
  google: PropTypes.shape({}).isRequired,
};
```