# Retrieve lat and long javascript

Tags: google-maps, jsp, coordinates, google-latitude

Basically I have an html page with a map where I find the latitude and the longitude that I want, and I have to send these coordinates to a jsp page, But when I press Send I get the error`java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1017)
    at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:540)`. So:

-in html I have

```
...<form action="GET.jsp" method="post" id="form" name="formMaps">
    <div id="map" style="float:left; width:100%; height:350px; margin-bottom:30px;"></div>
    Latitude <input type="String" name="lat" value="44.689205" id="coord_lat">
    <span style="margin-left:10px;">Longitude <input type="String" name="lon" value="10.663778" id="coord_lng"></span>
 <div align="center">        <input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" value="SEND"  /> </div></form>...
```

- in GET.JSP I have `...<%
   Double lati = Double.parseDouble(request.getParameter("lat"));
  Double longi = Double.parseDouble(request.getParameter("lon"));
     %>...`

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15417130/how-to-get-latitude-and-longitude-from-google-maps-v3-api

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should use input type text in your HTML code.

```
<input type="String" name="lat" value="44.689205" id="coord_lat">
```

replace this with

```
<input type="text" name="lat" value="44.689205" id="coord_lat">
```